# Undefined on Google Map Api v3 Reverse Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined is not a function, Google Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798431/undefined-is-not-a-function-google-geolocation)

I am trying to get google reverse geocoding of location, it returns me undefined but on console.log it shows address

this is the function to get the value

```
function getLatLng(latlng, callback) {
    var codedAddress;

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383)}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            codedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
            console.log("codedAddress 1 = "+codedAddress);
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem with the map");
        }
        console.log("codedAddress 2 = "+codedAddress);
    });
    callback(codedAddress);
}
```

and this is my init code

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.386, 100.245),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var location_coords = [
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    ];

    var location_status = [
        <?php echo $status; ?>
    ];

    var location_users = [
        <?php echo $users; ?>
    ];

    var location_date = [
        <?php echo $date; ?>
    ];

    for(i=0;i<location_coords.length;i++) {
      var traffic_options = {
        strokeColor: '#A52A2A',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: getColor(location_status[i]),
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        map: map,
        center: location_coords[i],
        radius: 300
      };
      cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(traffic_options);

    barr[i] = new Object;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location_coords[i],
        map: map,
    });

    barr[i].marker = marker;
    barr[i].html = "<div><span style='font-size:9px'>Reported by " + location_users[i] + " on " + location_date[i] + "</span>" +
        "Traffic Location: " + getLatLng(location_coords[i], function(codedAddress) { return codedAddress; }) + 
        "<p>Traffic Condition: " + getCondition(location_status[i]) + "</p></div>";

    barr[i].infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: barr[i].html
    });

    barr[i].listener = makeClosure(i, barr[i].marker);
    }
}
```

The problem is within this statement

```
"Traffic Location: " + getLatLng(location_coords[i], function(codedAddress) { return codedAddress; })
```

How do i get the value over here instead of "undefined"

Thank you

Comment: Where is <code>getLatLng()</code> defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the callback to be within the google maps callback function:

```
function getLatLng(latlng, callback) {
  var codedAddress;

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383)}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        codedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
        console.log("codedAddress 1 = "+codedAddress);
      } else {
        alert("There was a problem with the map");
      }
      console.log("codedAddress 2 = "+codedAddress);
      callback(codedAddress); //moved here
  });
  //it was here
}
```

Because you were calling the callback before the Google API had populated the variable.

Edit:
You will also need to modify the code that writes out the location, as that assumes the function call is synchronous.

e.g. something like:

```
getLatLng(location_coords[i], function(codedAddress) {
    barr[i].html = "<div><span style='font-size:9px'>Reported by " + location_users[i] + " on " + location_date[i] + "</span>" +
      "Traffic Location: " + codedAddress;  + 
      "<p>Traffic Condition: " + getCondition(location_status[i]) + "</p></div>";
});
```

Comment: Edited to include the use of the function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'html' of undefined, inside the block of getLatLng. do you know why?

Comment: You need to ensure the `bar[i]` variable is in scope (also ensure that `i` is the current value by using a separate function or a closure). You probably want to read up on the difference between asyncronous functions and syncronous functions (you are expecting the latter but getting the former from the Google API)

Answer (score 0):

Within getLatLng() (doh, there it is...) you need to move `callback(codedAddress);` to within the geocode call (and use the latlng argument):

```
function getLatLng(latlng, callback) {
  var codedAddress;

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, 
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        codedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
        console.log("codedAddress 1 = "+codedAddress);
      } else {
        alert("There was a problem with the map");
      }
      console.log("codedAddress 2 = "+codedAddress);
    }

    callback(codedAddress);
  );      
}
```

This function will return void, so your callback should initialise the `barr` object.